# joomla 1.7 how can I show the author and the created date in the Introtexts of the blogview

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to put some php snippets in some joomla articles, to have a more custom layout.

echo article->author;
echo article->created;

It works pretty well in the article view (Fulltext view) of joomla but I can't get it to work in the joomla Blogview (Introtext)

So my question Is how can I show the author and the created date in the Introtexts of the blogview.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by manipulating the `views` inside the `com_content`

You see, the views folder contain the following :

[image: Views folder of com_content]

It pretty much explain itself.

1. archive is for the archive view
2. article is for single article view
3. categories is for list of categories
4. category is the view of articles list inside a single category
5. featured is for featured items
6. form is for the insert new article form

What you are trying to edit is the blog view. Inside the category view open up the tmpl folder and edit the `blog_item.php` and insert your code.

Please note it's not a good idea to modify the core files. Copy the file to:

`your_template/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php` and make your edits, save and it will be used as an override.

If you still need help about the code you should post I will be glad to help.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for your Answer and sorry for the late reply, I didnt check stackoverflow for a while.

What I ment was not to edit the joomla html template files (I know how to do that) but to have some php output from inside the contentfields itself.

maybe this discussion helps to understand what I ment: http://www.nonumber.nl/component/kunena/14-sourcerer/21102-echo-article-gauthor-in-blog-item-introtexts